# Error about synrgyhk.dll when starting Synergy

Tags: synergy

Every once in a while, when I start Synergy on Windows, I get this message:

```
failed to init synrgyhk.dll, another program may be using it
```

How can I resolve this? The only workaround I've found is to restart the computer, but is there a better fix?

Answer (score 14):

1. Download [Process Explorer](http://download.cnet.com/Process-Explorer/3000-2094_4-10223605.html)
2. Run it, and search for *synergy* by clicking on the little binoculars
3. Kill all processes using the troubling dll (synrgyhk.dll) - be careful here to not kill anything important
4. I had to kill a process called `splwow64.exe` that had a handle on that dll for some reason, and everything worked great after

Comment: Another note, I was experiencing problems after a while again, but realized the batteries in my mouse were dying this time!

Comment: You can also try stopping/starting service in Services, and reset your settings (it's in Regedit, search for it.) With all these three, I managed to fix some weird issue... (no specific error, it just died on me.)

Comment: In my case it was google chrome...

Comment: Was google chrome here too...strange

Comment: Had this occur on both my servers today.  The first (Vista machine) I just uninstalled the program restarted and that fixed it.  On my current machine (also Vista) I had to do as described here, and found dmw.exe to be the culprit (as well as iTunesHelper, and a bunch of other seemingly unrelated programs.   Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't find a solution from the synergy Q&A's site, but I found it here. Run `services.msc` and restart Synergy service. It should allow you to start the server now. Thanks [Shiki](https://superuser.com/users/16001/shiki) for the suggestion. I, however, didn't need to reset the configuration in the registry. I'm thankful for that since my password is 30 digits and I don't remember it.

Answer (score 3):

Option A

1. Go to Run, type services.msc
2. Stop the Synergy service and start it again.
3. Start Synergy app and voila! No need to restart PC.

Option B (on windows 8.1)

1. Open task manager
2. Go to Services
3. Stop the Synergy service and start it again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you provide any more context around why your answer fits the question? Why OP might be getting the messages?

Comment: @CallumDA33, different versions of Synergy behave differently. Here's one [useful thread](https://github.com/synergy/synergy/issues/4951) in product support db, someone says, *"several processes should be able to access the same dll. and they do so.. but sometimes Synergy Pro 1.7.4 (latest build) is troubling it."*, and the best suggested solution is *"Usually, the simplest way to fix that is to restart the Windows synergy service"*. I doubt anybody can tell more than this.

Answer (score 0):

Just download: [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/#download), and navigate to the installation folder of Synergy. Right click the synrghyk.dll, choose Unlocker and kill all processes with it. Then it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Happened on my Windows 7 64-bit Synergy Server today...

Possible trigger... the whole machine hiccuped briefly as I tried to access an external drive that had gone to sleep. When the machine resumed, Synergy did not.

Solution:

- In Windows Task Manager I brought up "Processes, All users" and killed anything with "Synergy" in the name.
- I then went to "Services" and did a "Start" on the Synergy service.
- Then I restarted Synergy (the app) and it worked.

The order is important, because I tried to do those steps in different orders and it didn't work because the Synergy process keeps the Synergy Service from shutting down, etc.